# Laurent's series and finding the image of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series

Let $f$ be a complex function $f(z) = \frac{z^2 +1}{z(z-i)^3}$. It needs to be put jnto Laurent's series, so that it will converge in a set $D = \{ g(z) \mid Re(z) > 0 \}$, where  $g(z) = \frac{2iz}{z-1}$.

I've been struggling with finding this set $D$. So the singularities for $f$ are $z = 0$ and $z = i$. Where should I even have the center of the series?

Comment: Can you clarify how the set $D$ is defined?

Comment: It's the image of the map $g$ of the right half of the plane. So if $R_+ = (0, \infty ) \times (- \infty , \infty )$, then the set $D = g( R_+ )$

Comment: So you mean $D = \{ g(z) \mid \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0  \}$ ?

Comment: Are  you aware that $g$ is a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation)?

Comment: Yes, that's how $D$ is defined. No, I did not think of that. But how could this fact help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to write  $g$ as a composition of “simple” transformations:
$$
 g(z) = 2i \left( 1 + \frac{1}{z-1}\right)
$$
and then successively determine the image of the right half-plane.

Another option is to use that fact that $g$ is a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation): It maps the imaginary axis to a circle (or line), and that image is uniquely determined by the image of three distinct points. From
$$
 g(-i) = -1+i, g(0) = 0, g(+i) = 1+i
$$
you can conclude that the imaginary axis is mapped to the circle with center $i$ and radius $1$. It follows that the right half-plane is mapped to the inside or outside of that circle. Since $g(1) = \infty$, we have
$$
 D = \{ g(z) : \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0  \} = \{ w : |w-i| > 1 \} \, .
$$

That is an annulus with center $i$, inner radius $1$ and outer radius $\infty$. Your task is now to determine the Laurent series of $f$ in that annulus.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The function $f(x)$ diverges only in its singularities. So do any of those singularities belong to the inside or on the boundary of $D$?

Comment: Alright, so I don't need to do anything with $D$ then? As I see that neither of the singularity points are in $D$, as both have the real part equal to $0$, I just make the series. Does it matter around which point do I make the series? Can I yust use $0$ as the center?